# How to choose permissions for a Google Container Engine cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to setup a GKE cluster and I want to enable all permissions to other services (since apparently you can't change the permissions after the cluster has been created). This ought to be straight-forward but either I'm doing something wrong or something is broken. I select the following for my project access:

[image]

But when the cluster is created a see this:

[image]

I.e. everything is disabled. Why is this? How do I set the permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in the UI that was showing that all scopes were disabled. I just created a new cluster and the UI is showing the correct scopes.

If this happens again, you can also see the scopes that are enabled on your VMs using the command line by running `gcloud container clusters describe NAME --zone=europe-west1-c` and looking at the scopes under `oauthScopes:`.

Comment: I see not options to select permission when creating a cluster :/ the only near similar is in Security "Enable basic authentication" and "Issue a client certificate"

Comment: The UI has changed a lot in the last few years. :) In the UI today, you will get a default node pool, which has a button called "Advanced edit". Scroll down until you find "Access scopes" and click the radio button for "Set access for each API". This allows you to set the scopes that are applied to all of the VMs in that node pool.

Comment: Thanks :D I thought that option was only to customize the machine type no to assing permissions as well, I think that must be changed, but anyway thanks :D